# How to output 311 Mio. m³ using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

How can I use `\SI{value}{unit}` in combination with the abbreviation for million (Mio.)?

Only way I found is

```
311 Mio. \si{\cubic\metre}
```

Comment: You can define `\DeclareSIUnit{\mio}{\text{Mio.}}`-> `\si{311}{\mio\cubic\metre}`

Comment: It may interest you to note that this abbreviation for million is not necessarily that well known. I had never heard of it before this question; [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mio), it’s used solely in some financial markets (e.g. German, Swiss, Dutch).

Comment: @KRyan: It's a rather frequent abbreviation in German texts in general. I've got no idea why the Wikipedia article uses the somewhat odd phrase "in some financial markets" instead of "in some languages".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\million}{\text{Mio.}}

\begin{document}
\SI{300}{\million\cubic\metre}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Or you could use a prefix to your unit.

*(Caveat: I don't know how to prevent the prefix from becoming cubed, so I used `2` in the definition instead of `6`)*

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIPrefix{\million}{\text{Mio. }}{2}

\begin{document}
\SI{300}{\million\metre\cubed}

\SI[prefixes-as-symbols=false]{300}{\million \metre\cubed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Two additional possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI[parse-numbers=false]{311~Mio.}{\cubic\meter}

311 Mio.\,m\textsuperscript{3}
\end{document}
```